# If statements with functions in java

Tags: java, if-statement

So I'm trying to calculate National insurance and I am using 3 IF statements.

```
/does not work
public double calculateNotContOut(){
    if (calculateWeeklyEarning()<upperEarningLevel){
        return (((calculateWeeklyEarning()-primaryThreshold)*primaryClassBetween)*52);
    }
    else {
        return (((upperEarningLevel-primaryThreshold)*primaryClassBetween+(calculateWeeklyEarning()-upperEarningLevel)*primaryClassAbove)*52);
    }
}
//does not work
public double calculateContOut(){
    if (calculateWeeklyEarning()<upperEarningLevel){
        return (((calculateWeeklyEarning()-primaryThreshold)*calculateReducedContribution())*52);
    }
    else{
        return (((upperEarningLevel-primaryThreshold)*calculateReducedContribution()+(calculateWeeklyEarning()-upperEarningLevel)*primaryClassAbove)*52);
    }
}

public double calculateNationalInsurance(){
    if (contractedOut){
        return (calculateContOut());
    }
    else {
        return (calculateNotContOut());
    }
}
```

They do not return the correct value. Can someone help?

Comment: and in what way does it not work?

Comment: @user2110669: To help you out we at least have to know your method definitions and what the types of your variables are. Also, saying "_They do not return the correct value_" isn't very specific. What's your input? What output do you expect (and why)? What's the actual output?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is the if statement? maybe its the complex calculation you do there?

Comment: It will never return the correct value even if your logic is correct because you are using `double`.

Answer (score 1):

In Java if condition deals with only `Boolean` type or `boolean` premitive.

makesure return value of `calculateWeeklyEarning()` and `upperEarningLevel` are compariable

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the calculateWeeklyEarning() is being returned less than or equal to upperEarningLevel. There is no problem in the if statement.